# FOSOAuthServerBundle translate error messages

Tags: php, symfony, fosoauthserverbundle

I installed `FOSOAuthServerBundle` and everything went well, but I don't know how to translate error messages like this:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type
>   parameter or parameter missing"}

I want to provide translation for error messages in languages other than English (e.g. French). Any solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "translate"? Can you provide some code you've written?

Comment: error messages written in English but i want them to be in French.

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/issues/433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a friend tell me that he resolved it with extending **OAuth2/OAuth2** class and overriding methods.
You can override the default package class OAuth2 in services.yml:

```
parameters:
    fos_oauth_server.server.class: My\Bundle\OAuth2\OAuth2
```

it may be a **solution** but it should be an other solution with **configuration**